# Why i cant input jquery created elements in react render

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs

I realy realy new with react, and i'm trying to create a simple element on my page using Jquery, but is not working. See te code bellow:

```
  // inside src/index.js
  import React from 'react'
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
  import $ from 'jquery'


    const element = ($("<h1>",{
      html: "Try"
    }));
    ReactDOM.render(element , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why it is no possible? there is any whay to do that?

Comment: there's no way google doesn't have a nice answer for this.

Comment: i whas searching for more than 4 hours, just tutorials teaching how use react, thats anoying .

Comment: react replaces jquery. react only renders `jsx` (or direct calls to `React.createElement`). you should be using jquery as little as possible, and definitely not trying to render jquery elements. (you could use `.html()` on your element to render it inside a jsx element, but shouldn't)

Comment: Thanks fot helping a noob !